# How to handle routing with overlapping ranges as general concept?

Tags: routing, network

An existing network managed by a 3rd party contains routers of the same subnet (in this case `192.168.0.0/24`) and is connected to a central infrastructure using a VPN tunnel. All connections are force to go through the tunnel, i.e. `Router A` and `Router B` are not able to directly communicate with each other, but only to send and receive packages through the tunnel. The routers manage internal networks with overlapping ranges between them. There is no way to change the Router Network or its configuration.

For a custom, arbitrary central instance where the tunnel terminates, I am looking for a solution to connect the routers with additional external networks. For those, again an IPsec tunnel is established, and again we might have overlapping IP addresses.

Simplified, I am looking for a way to provide routing according to the dotted lines in scale. My main problem are the overlapping network ranges, and the individual target routers of the `192.168.0.0/24` range.

What method / technology of dynamic routing would you suggest to create *virtual networks* containing the corresponding pairs (*Router N, Cloud Network N*)? From my understanding BGP won't help here, as I couldn't define a distinct set of AS without overlapping range. Could you please push me in a direction to look into?

[image]

Comment: If you have overlapping subnets, then NAT is your only real answer.  Since you can't modify the router network, you will have to do NAT in your cloud network.

Comment: For overlapping IP addresses, you use NAT. That was created for just such a situation. There are various forms of NAT, including Outside-Source NAT that is use for instances where companies with overlapping network addressing merge. Such a situation _should_ be temporary until one or both networks can be re-addressed.